# jQuery selector for newer HTML5 inputs not working

Tags: jquery

I have an array that outputs inputs, with a type of number, but i cant seem to get the selector to find it. Is it not supported?

```
$('#container :text').each(...
$('#container input:number').each(...
$('#container :number').each(...
```

None of them find the input values. What am i missing?

I also looked at the selector list on the jQuery site, and did not see anything for newer HTML5 input types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery *currently* does not support some pseudo-selectors. You will instead need to base your query off of the attributes of the target element(s), as demonstrated below.

```js
$("#container input[type=number]");
```

As of jQuery 1.9.0, these are the following pseudo-selectors stored under `jQuery.expr[":"]`:

```js
["animated", "button", "checkbox", "checked", "contains", "disabled", "empty", 
 "enabled", "eq", "even", "file", "first", "focus", "gt", "has", "header", 
 "hidden", "image", "input", "lang", "last", "lt", "not", "nth", "odd", 
 "parent", "password", "radio", "reset", "root", "selected", "submit", "target", 
 "text", "visible"]
```

You can extend this object and provide your own custom selectors if you like:

```js
$.extend( $.expr[":"], {
    'color': function ( elem ) {
        return /color/.test(elem.type);
    }
});
```

Comment: Took care of it, thanks! Still learning all the ins and out to jQuery

Comment: is the colon before input a mistake?

Comment: @lliaG No, it matches `input`, `textarea` and more. All forms of input. Granted, it's not really necessary in this case since `type=number` only applies to `input` elements.